# When will this cron run

Tags: cron

Cron:

`* */6 * * * /path/to/command`

I want this cron to run once in every 6 hour.

Whats wrong with the above cron definition, and why?

Comment: You don't even tell us whether that is the system crontab or a user crontab?

Comment: That'll run every single minute of every sixth hour, every day, every week, every month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify a minute value in the first column. The star there makes it run on each minute value.

```
10 */6 * * * /path/to/command
```

will make it run 10 minutes past the hour, every six hours (on all days).

From `man 5 crontab`: *A   field   may   be   an   asterisk  (`*`),  which  always  stands  for 'first-last'*. This implies all possible values.

Comment: will having * on the minute value make it to run, more than once.

Comment: Yes every minute

Comment: Does that mean that the cron will run 6o times , on every 6th hour.

Comment: I expect your cron to do that yes. Because mine has a 10 in the first position, it will only run 10 past every 6 hours.

Answer (score 2):

It is not portable.

This one should always work:

```
0 0,6,12,18 * * * /path/to/command
```

Comment: @Anthon I did it as soon as I posted it but you definitely were faster to answer. You are likely right the main issue is there and not on the */6 portability.

Comment: @jillagre I did see a star there, now there is none, without your post showing an edit. So you must have corrected it while I commented. I will remove the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Cron job simulators to validate you Job run schedule.

Link for one of the cron job simulator - http://www.dataphyx.com/cronsandbox/